Inserting data to clickhouse nested column using python client
I have a column sample_column which is a Tuple (score string, threshold string), in clickhouse. I tried the Python client insert method and used both ways below, but couldn't get the insert to work.
Method 1
client.insert( table='my_table', data = [[1]], column_names=['sample_column[score]'])

Method 2
client.insert( table='my_table', data = [[1]], column_names=['sample_column.score'])

Is there a proper way to do it?
I tried both these code samples.

I use this approach and it works perfectly
from clickhouse_driver import Client

def insert_data(data_tuples):
    conn = Client(
        host='localhost',
        port=9000,
        user='',
        password=''
    )

    query = "INSERT INTO default.your_table(column1, column2) VALUES"

    conn.execute(query, data_tuples, types_check=True)
    conn.disconnect()

